# HTTP keep-alive with C++ recv winsocket2

Tags: c++, http, keep-alive, recv

I'm Coding my own HTTP fetcher socket. I use C++ in MVC++ and winsocket2.h 
I was able to program the socket to connect to the required website's server  and send an HTTP GET request.

Now the problem is after I send an HTTP GET request with Keep-alive connection, I call the recv function , and it works fine except after it retrieves  the website, it stays lingering and waiting for time-out hint from the server or a connection to close!!

This takes a few seconds of less depending in the keep-alive timeout the servers has, 
Therefore, I can't benefit from the keep-alive HTTP settings.

How can I tell the recv function to stop after retrieving the website and gives back the command to me so I can send another HTTP request while avoiding another hand-shake regime.

When I use the non-blocking sockets it works faster, But I don't know when to stop, I set a str.rfind("",-1,7) to stop retrieving  data.
however, it is not very efficient.

Does anybody know a way to do it, or what is that last character send by the HTTP server when the connection is kept alive, so I can use it as a stopping decision.

Best,
Moe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for a `Content-Length: xxxxx` header, and only read xxxxx bytes after the header, which is terminated by a blank line (CR-LF-CR-LF in stream).

#### update

If the data is chunked:

> Chunked Transfer-Encoding ([reference](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#http1.1c2))
>
> ...
>
> A chunked message body contains a
> series of chunks, followed by a line
> with "0" (zero), followed by optional
> footers (just like headers), and a
> blank line. Each chunk consists of two
> parts:
>
> - a line with the size of the chunk
>   data, in hex, possibly followed by a
>   semicolon and extra parameters you can
>   ignore (none are currently standard),
>   and ending with CRLF.
> - the data itself,
>   followed by CRLF.

Also, http://www.w3.org description of Chunked Transfer-Encoding is in section 3.6.1 @ http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html.

Comment: How can you know the length with the data is Chunked , No Content-Length Header is sent then !!

Answer (score 0):

Set the non-blocking I/O flag on the socket, so that `recv` will return immediately with only as much data has already been received.  Combine this with `select`, `WSAEventSelect`, `WSAAsyncSelect`, or completion ports to be informed when data arrives (instead of busy-waiting).